# pdb.set_trace alternative with apache/wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, pdb, django-wsgi

I have just migrated my development enviroment from manage.py to apache/wsgi, how ever when I run  pdb.set_trace() I get BdbQuit. Is there a way to work with something like pdb.set_trace under apache/wsgi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a remote debugger.  Look into rpdb2 here: http://winpdb.org/docs/embedded-debugging/

Of course, Apache+WSGI is typically a production environment and is going to be harder to debug then running the development appserver with manage.py.

Comment: The fact of being possible only one request at the time, makes manage.py difficult to use because the kind of project that I am working right now. For now is easier to keep debugging with end-user messages, how ever is very helpful to know winpdb exists for REAL bugs, thanks.